# Reading binary files in python

Tags: python, binary

I have a binary file which I would like to read with python. I know that the first 493 bytes are x-values, the next 87 bytes are y-values and the last 147 bytes are z-values. I have written some code which should do this as shown below:

```
with open("file", "rb") as fileHandle:
    byte = fileHandle.read(1)

    datax = []
    datay = []
    dataz = []

    dim_x = 493
    dim_y = 87
    dim_z = 147

    while fileHandle.tell() < dim_x + dim_y + dim_z:
        byte = fileHandle.read(1)

        if fileHandle.tell() < dim_x:
            datax.append(byte)

        if dim_x < fileHandle.tell() < dim_x + dim_y:
            datay.append(byte)

        if dim_x + dim_y < fileHandle.tell() < dim_x + dim_y + dim_z:
            dataz.append(byte)

    print fileHandle.tell()
    print len(fileHandle.read())
```

However, when I compare `fileHandle.tell()` and `len(fileHandle.read())` yields 727 and 6304250, respectively. This must mean that I am only getting part of my data? I thought fileHandle.read(1) would step through the file byte by byte? What am I missing here?

On a nother note, how do I plot these data in a simple contour plot in Python? Is matplotlib the way to go?

Comment: Stackoverflow is designed so questions and answers form a repository of solutions that can be used in the future.  Asking two questions at once breaks that model - please split this into two questions.

Comment: You've constructed the `while` loop so that it continues until you're at position 727 in the file.  Apparently your file is much longer than that - 6304250 + 727 = 6304977 bytes in fact.  Why do you think your file should be only 727 bytes long?

Comment: `len(fileHandle.read())` is telling you how many _unread_ bytes are in the file after you've read 727 of them. If the file is anywhere near that long, you must be misunderstanding its format. It seems odd that there aren't an equal number of x, y, and z values (not to mention that they're only one byte values).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make the initial comparisons non-strict, i.e.:

```
if dim_x <= fileHandle.tell() < dim_x + dim_y:
```

Second thing: your file has apparently 727+6304250 bytes. The last read call returns all remaining bytes you have not read. Yes, you get only a part of your data, since you requested only first 727 bytes.

There are many more efficient and pythonic ways to do this, though.

Answer (score 0):

[I'm only a beginner at Python, so I may have misunderstood some things.]

I can see a few problems with this program, and maybe one to explain the numbers you see.

1. The first byte of the file is read by the second line of the program, so is not saved as an X value. You should probably delete that line.
2. Your if statements do nothing when tell() has the values 493 or 580. You need a couple of  <=. Something like this will catch them:

> ```
>     if fileHandle.tell() < dim_x:
>         datax.append(byte)
>
>     if dim_x <= fileHandle.tell() < dim_x + dim_y:
>         datay.append(byte)
>
>     if dim_x + dim_y <= fileHandle.tell() < dim_x + dim_y + dim_z:
>         dataz.append(byte)
> ```

1. If your file is exactly 493+87+147 = 727 bytes long, you will actually have read beyond the end of the file by three bytes. I'm not sure what happens when you do that. Probably an error message.
2. The last line actually tries to read everything left in the file. So it looks like your file is much longer than 727 bytes. In fact, I would guess that it is 727+6304250=6304977 bytes long.

Comment: You're right. I've misunderstood the documentation. Actually the file is a matrix consisting of 493x87x147 elements giving the correct number of bytes.